# Android canvas draw

Tags: android, canvas, android-canvas

How to draw on canvas two texts with relative positioning?
Example:

```
User: John Doe
Status: foreigner
```

Code used produce text "one on top of another" issue:

```
Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();
    int titleBaseLine = 72;
    int leftMargin = 54;
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setTextSize(40);
    canvas.drawText(user, leftMargin, titleBaseLine, paint);
    canvas.drawText(userName, leftMargin, titleBaseLine, paint);
```

Comment: "Relative positioning" is kinda meaningless without a better description. Anyway, the reason they're drawing one atop the other is because you're telling both to draw in the same place. Did you consult the docs for the [`Canvas#drawText()` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawText(java.lang.String,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint)) you're using?

Comment: Better description??? I gave an example... Did you look at it?

Comment: We have no way to know how that relates to your code. What are you talking about, specifically? The two separate lines? The colon separator on each single line? You didn't give values for the `String`s in the example `drawText()` calls.

Comment: problem is that "John Doe" is on top of "User"

Comment: Then the simplest fix for that would be to just concatenate the `"User:"` and `"John Doe"` `String`s, and make one `drawText()` call for that line.

Comment: The problem is that if I want to "User" to be bold I cannot do that in that way

Comment: Well, then the next simplest thing is probably to figure the x-coordinate for the second `String` by using `Paint#measureText()` to get the width of the first from the `Paint` object used to draw it.

Comment: That's I don't know how to do

Comment: Well, I'm on a phone, atm, and don't really have time to Swype a whole answer for this, but in your example, you would change the `leftMargin` argument in the second `drawText()` call to something like `leftMargin + paint.measureText(user)`, plus wherever other spacing you want in there. Of course, if one `String` is bold, and the other isn't, you'll have to use two different `Paint` objects, or measure the text width before you change the attributes on the one `Paint` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final answer:

```
int titleBaseLine = 60;
int leftMargin = 20;
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
paint.setTextSize(40);
Paint paintBold = new Paint();         
paintBold.setTypeface(Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT,Typeface.BOLD));
paintBold.setColor(Color.BLACK);
paintBold.setTextSize(40);

canvas.drawText(userText, leftMargin + leftMargin, titleBaseLine, paintBold);
canvas.drawText(username, leftMargin + paintBold.measureText(userText) + leftMargin + 10, titleBaseLine, paint);
canvas.drawText(statusText, leftMargin + leftMargin, titleBaseLine * 2, paintBold);
canvas.drawText(statusName, leftMargin + paintBold.measureText(statusText) + leftMargin + 10, titleBaseLine * 2, paint);
```